# Retriving data from firebase to populate a RecyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I want to retrieve some data from FireBase in order to populate a RecyclerView.My app idea is : a user picks some locations from a map fragment and then stores them in Firebase Database.Those saved locations are displayed in a Places fragment where I want to use a RecylcerView.When I run the app i get the following errors

```
08-29 23:01:35.257 25039-25039/com.aplicatiechat.mcristi.firebaseandmapsdemoforlearning E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.aplicatiechat.mcristi.firebaseandmapsdemoforlearning, PID: 25039
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class com.aplicatiechat.mcristi.firebaseandmapsdemoforlearning.Places is missing a constructor with no arguments
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekq.zze(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zzb(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.ClassSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot(ClassSnapshotParser.java:22)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.ObservableSnapshotArray.getObject(ObservableSnapshotArray.java:141)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.CachingObservableSnapshotArray.getObject(CachingObservableSnapshotArray.java:40)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getItem(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:127)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:164)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6673)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6714)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5647)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5913)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5752)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5748)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2232)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1559)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1519)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:614)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3812)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3529)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:1767)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(RecyclerView.java:356)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:559)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

This is my Places Fragment:

```
 public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.places_fragment, container, false);
        mRecylcerView = mView.findViewById(R.id.places);
        mRecylcerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecylcerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        return mView;

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        mDataBase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(mFirebaseUser.getUid());
        DatabaseReference places = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).child("place");
        DatabaseReference keys = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).child("key");
        FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter<Places,PlacesViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter<Places,PlacesViewHolder>(Places.class,R.layout.place_layout,PlacesViewHolder.class,places,keys) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(PlacesViewHolder viewHolder, Places model, int position) {
                viewHolder.setLat(model.getLat());
                viewHolder.setLon(model.getLon());
            }
        };
        mRecylcerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }

}
class PlacesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    View mView;
    private TextView lat;
    private TextView lon;


    public PlacesViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
        lat = mView.findViewById(R.id.lat_view);
        lon = mView.findViewById(R.id.lon_view);
    }

    public void setLat(String n){
        lat.setText(n);
    }

    public void setLon(String e){
        lon.setText(e);
    }
}
```

and here it is my Model Places class:

```
public class Places extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private String lat;
    private String lon;

    public Places(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }


    public String getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(String lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public String getLon() {
        return lon;
    }

    public void setLon(String lon) {
        this.lon = lon;
    }

}
```

Here is a screenshow with my databse :
[Firebase database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsEDx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an empty constructor in your `Places` class as

```
public Places(){}
```

because firebase recycler adapter did not find this empty constructor in your Places class. And replace this

```
FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter<Places,PlacesViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter<Places,PlacesViewHolder>(Places.class,R.layout.place_layout,PlacesViewHolder.class,places,keys)
```

with

```
FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter<Places,PlacesViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter<Places,PlacesViewHolder>(Places.class,R.layout.place_layout,PlacesViewHolder.class,keys,places) {
```

And you need to remove the extend from Places class.

Comment: I get an error when I tried to implement the empty constructor: " Default constructor not available in android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;"

Comment: why you need to extends Places with RecyclerView.ViewHolder ? it is redundant

Comment: I removed the extended RecyclerView.ViewHolder but still the exception persists.

Comment: after removing the extend and there is a empty constructor present but the problem is still there?

Comment: "  com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.aplicatiechat.mcristi.firebaseandmapsdemoforlearning.Places" still the same problem

Comment: you are using wrong order. key retrieved first then there should be data. so in RecyclerIndexAdapter try using key reference first then place reference where as you are using place first and key reference